# mongodb Error: No primary found in set

Tags: mongodb

I am connecting to mongodb using mongodb native driver version(1.4.38).

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://primarydb.com:27017,secondarydb.com:27017/dbname?replicaSet=replsetname"

MongoClient.connect(url, {}, function (err, db) {

    console.log("Error >>>>>>>>>", err);
    console.log("db >>>>>>>>>", db);

})
```

It is working fine.

But when i am trying to connect only secondary db using

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://secondarydb.com:27017/dbname?replicaSet=replsetname"

MongoClient.connect(url, {}, function (err, db) {

    console.log("Error >>>>>>>>>", err);
    console.log("db >>>>>>>>>", db);

})
```

It is giving error :

Error: No primary found in set.

I have also tried 
var url = "mongodb://secondarydb.com:27017/dbname"

But still giving same here.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't connect to the secondary without having the primary (well, you can, kinda.. you just can't do anything). You could set your readPreference to read from secondary though - if that's your goal.

Comment: Thanks for comment. but I want to connect to secondary server only for some reason.

Comment: What reason do you want to connect to a slave?

Comment: For reporting purpose only. If it stop/fail, should not affect application.

Comment: Use the [arbitrator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/) to get a health check on slaves then.